# Page Tokens In Google Drive File List Request C++

Tags: c++, google-drive-api

In my research of the Drive API's File List Request, much has been made of the importance of checking the request's `nextPageToken` property, but as far as I can tell this property doesn't exist on the ListRequest object in C++\CLI.

Is there any equivalent way in C++/CLI to access page tokens (or otherwise make sure that a file request doesn't get stopped short by a maximum request restriction)?

Thanks!